# Set c++14 standard usage for nvcc in MSVC 2017

Tags: cuda, c++14

Stupid question, but I can not understand how to set up c++14 standard usage for nvcc in MSVS (MSVC). I tried to add "-std=c++14" in the Command Line and "/std:c++14" in "Additional Compiler Options", but got

`nvcc warning : The -std=c++14 flag is not supported with the configured host compiler. Flag will be ignored.`

How to correctly set up this option?

Comment: There is no need to use it on the windows platform.  Support for it is automatically enabled (in CUDA 9.x with VS2017)

Comment: @Robert Crovella, so, Is this correct that compilation errors in pair "Blaze+Thrust" are connected with Blaze and nvcc incompability? Because I can write simple code which is compiled by cl.exe fine, but failed to be compiled with nvcc (without any row of cuda code!)

Comment: It's quite possible.  That seems like a different question.

Comment: @Robert Crovella, It's so strange, really.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On windows platforms, the support for e.g. C++11 and C++14 is dictated by the platform.  It is already enabled (C++14 requires CUDA 9.x or later, C++11 was supported with earlier versions of CUDA such as CUDA 7.5).

This means that the support will be a function of which CUDA version and which Visual Studio version you are using, and there are no switches to pass to enable it.  Attempting to use a switch such as `-std=c++11` or `-std=c++14` will be met with a compile warning on windows.